# TypeScript Type on constructor to reference itself in extended class

Tags: typescript, types

This works but I was wondering if there is a better way of getting the constructor to know we want a `UserEntity` aka `typeof this`

```
class BaseEntity<T> {
  constructor(data: T) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}

class UserEntity extends BaseEntity<UserEntity> {
  name: string;
}

const user = new UserEntity({name: 'Bar'});
```

Now if I want to extend `UserEntity`, I'll have to `super` the constructor:

```
class UserWithRoles extends UserEntity {
  constructor(data: UserWithRoles) {
    super(data);
  }
  roles: string[];
}
```

I have a feeling there has to be a smarter way of defining the type in the `BaseEntity` constructor so extended classes would expect an object of itself and have typeing shout if data passed to constructor are missing properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to have *methods* on your entities, then you can simply use plain objects with interface:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
}

const user: User = { name: "Bar" };

interface UserWithRoles extends User {
  roles: string[];
}

const userWithRoles: UserWithRoles = {
  name: "Bar",
  roles: ["foo", "bar"],
}
```

---

If you *do* plan to have methods, then your strategy will become even more difficult, because instead of taking "This" as the constructor argument, you would need "This" but *without the methods*. It should be possible to specify such type, e.g. with a [Mapped Type excluding keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) which value type is a Function, but this assumes that all functions are methods (i.e. you do not expect callbacks as part of your "data"):

```
type WithoutMethods<T> = {
    [k in keyof T as T[k] extends Function ? never : k]: T[k]
};
```

Then make sure to propagate your generic type to each child class, so that further descendant class can re-specify it:

```
// Make sure that all child class also expose a generic type...
class UserEntity<T extends UserEntity<any>> extends BaseEntity<WithoutMethods<T>> {
    name: string; // BTW error: Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

    logName() { console.log(this.name); }
}

const user = new UserEntity({ name: "Bar" });
user.name;
user.logName();

// ...so that a further descendant class can re-specify it
class UserWithRoles<T extends UserWithRoles<any>> extends UserEntity<T> {
    roles: string[]; // BTW error: Property 'roles' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

    logRoles() { console.log(this.roles); }
}

const user2 = new UserWithRoles({
    name: "foo",
    roles: ["bar"]
});
user2.roles;
user2.logName();
user2.logRoles();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiA7ALgSzQTwDwBUA+aAbwChpLpgB7FCNAJwFdg0bGAKAEzDTABc0fAEpSFKpIDyAIwBWCNgDpIEDAHMUnNAAsMEADTRe-EQG4JlAL5kbZHAAcE0AOpYdNZmgCyCXTW4IAmIAXnFJAG0Aa2gMFGgohGwaADNhaEhhaIBdaAQADzQEFEDoADFmFDYMOmgAfmgUBAA3BEZoISjsoXwc2wt7bCdhBAZoMLd-L19-QNxySQB6RYA9OstGsABbBCEGRjj1C0kd2aFOMRDiZpoMbltCMjJl6G8wROgIZkZnXT4MkAgah6EDcajgKAAiA0PL5Bw0CDOMDQdTFNoYYDQRwIJS4sigVTQACqiMYqEwOAIsKKJRgJLa5KweDAKGwhGIBRppXgiMZlMmHmmfg8cyIxAWVBQ212nyYhzM0BesHwLjyjEYHCEAAUNU5GDhoAByKU7Q3QHSZFAwuJYDBgEAYABebQyJViMCtaGMCBSNqKIGwGSgGiaYLiWJ0zlo9CYrHYjCUT0kIBo6gActKLqRqHRoSAcSn1No9BAlCaEOZoDY7NGxsxSeNGggAO7E0l87CcEibHZCABE8EYfar5jI9baZelFnHCcLGZ2FwGL1xSmhEf+yJS310Lu4o2AxV46HBhOALOgPwAtBAnMAMClA1h8RC6aSBQAlGj5oL4amH19tB+X6jLgLJshyhT-m2DLoEywThFQGrfnscooOoETZAqSoqmqGqMNquptAahpIaMZoWh61ooLa9pOi6LJhpRXp7r61H+oGqghggYbxDuOYxiwbAcImGyFp+35Zt2tbAUohbFvoSikRAlbVk8tZejOABMjZNK29KMEBEkSpQ5b9ikNA0H2BgbEpQgRH2MhgEO2S2KOWmKcBEDTqSmmyam84IIuY4+X56jiaMQVAA)

(BTW note that TS still reports errors on the fields, because it does not know they are assigned through `Object.assign()`)

And we have type checking for missing properties in the constructor, as desired:

```
const userFail = new UserEntity({}); // Error: Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'WithoutMethods<UserEntity<any>>'.
//                              ~~

const user2Fail = new UserWithRoles({
    name: "Bar" // Error: Property 'roles' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'WithoutMethods<UserWithRoles<any>>
    //~~~~~~~~~
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiA7ALgSzQTwDwBUA+aAbwChpLpgB7FCNAJwFdg0bGAKAEzDTABc0fAEpSFKpIDyAIwBWCNgDpIEDAHMUnNAAsMEADTRe-EQG4JlAL5kbZHAAcE0AOpYdNZmgCyCXTW4IAmIAXnFJAG0Aa2gMFGgohGwaADNhaEhhaIBdaAQADzQEFEDoADFmFDYMOmgAfmgUBAA3BEZoISjsoXwc2wt7bCdhBAZoMLd-L19-QNxySQB6RYA9OstGsABbBCEGRjj1C0kd2aFOMRDiZpoMbltCMjJl6G8wROgIZkZnXT4MkAgah6EDcajgKAAiA0PL5Bw0CDOMDQdTFNoYYDQRwIJS4sigVTQACqiMYqEwOAIsKKJRgJLa5KweDAKGwhGIBRppXgiMZlMmHmmfg8cyIxAWVBQ212nyYhzM0BesHwLjyjEYHCEAAUNU5GDhoAByKU7Q3QHSZFAwuJYDBgEAYABebQyJViMCtaGMCBSNqKIGwGSgGiaYLiWJ0zlo9CYrHYjCUT0kIBo6gActKLqRqHRoSAcSn1No9BAlCaEOZoDY7NGxsxSeNGggAO7E0l87CcEibHZCABE8EYfar5jI9baZelFnHCcLGZ2FwGL1xSmhEf+yJS310Lu4o2AxV46HBhOALOgPwAtBAnMAMClA1h8RC6aSBQAlGj5oL4amH19tB+X6jLgLJshyhT-m2DLoEywThFQGrfnscooOoETZAqSoqmqGqMNquptAahpIaMZoWh61ooLa9pOi6LJhpRXp7r61H+oGqghggYbxDuOYxiwbAcImGyFp+35Zt2tbAUohbFvoSikRAlbVk8tZejOABMjZNK29KMEBEkSpQ5b9ikNA0H2BgbEpQgRH2MhgEO2S2KOWmKcBEDTqSmmyam84IIuY4+X56jiaMQX4rmGmkmUYAYECYS6dBZKwTgXZWJWLxIOqmrQDqNB6sR5Zmvo0BbPoahobEvFDM4hokFYZoyF4F4IAAjswGA-DxWJ1UaAqeD4woBEE+kdqBrLsoaiYvJI80LYti0AH7LWp0XQFpcUJTpLYpYZEXGT2MoDk5w7Zbl+H5YR+qBiRnmlTAFXBtV4bYka3ambKBxoQqTXQC1Xo-J13XcTVfXDIag1CrMY1vu44VBGB02JksiyrRjmOuRYQA)

---

But in that case, a more simple and robust solution consists in *nesting* your data, e.g. in a `data` sub-property of your class, so that it is clearly separated from your methods, and you can also directly assign it with TypeScript constructor [Parameter Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) (hence even saving the explicit call to `Object.assign()`):

> TypeScript offers special syntax for turning a constructor parameter into a class property with the same name and value. These are called *parameter properties* and are created by prefixing a constructor argument with one of the visibility modifiers `public`, `private`, `protected`, or `readonly`.

```
class BaseEntity<T> {
    // Constructor Parameter Property
    constructor(public data: T) { }
}

interface UserEntityData {
    name: string
}

class UserEntity<T extends UserEntityData> extends BaseEntity<T> {
    logName() { console.log(this.data.name); }
}

const user = new UserEntity({ name: 'Bar' });
user.data.name; // Okay
user.logName();

interface UserWithRolesData extends UserEntityData {
    roles: string[]
}

class UserWithRoles<T extends UserWithRolesData> extends UserEntity<T> {
    logRoles() { console.log(this.data.roles); }
}

const userWithRoles = new UserWithRoles({
    name: "foo",
    roles: ["bar"]
});
userWithRoles.data.roles; // Okay
userWithRoles.logName();
userWithRoles.logRoles();

const userFail = new UserEntity({}); // Error: Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'UserEntityData'.
//                              ~~

const userWithRolesFail = new UserWithRoles({
    name: "Bar" // Error: Property 'roles' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'UserWithRolesData'.
    //~~~~~~~~~
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiA7ALgSzQTwDwBUA+aAbwChpLoB6a6AYQHsUI0AnAV2DUbegAUwbMAFsEaBH35tGAB0k4KVYM1aduvABSyOAIxAZg0ACZg0YAFzR8ASlLQAvmSdkM6SQDMwwBNACqEJKomDgAImZgpEqUKKIIVmpuAObOZGSgkDABQehYePjQCAAeEijGWYFswXnh5sTFpeVwiNU4BMTkVNAgjEkAcnGadiTQKiyMIAgAdD1JmmgAFhgQU6bmU7FiNgDcjqnpqmjQHJXQALzQKAgA7v6VrdiaI5vx0ADk8GxvjjtkJ5KrCIbOK7WjQADyAGswNg-pUZr0BmIhts0m4JGwvD47pIAOpYBYAJQmCAgtUiDQQZQqORC2HJUS6MkmEAS7GSAG0ALr7DJQHFsfGLYksgiFEpUprZQUEkWk8n1CXUgUPdqMqizOUQIb2MYQEkIuaLZaA9bM0k7PYuPVHf4y4UkmAXK63aVComOp7RS5xKwAIg8jEYfoANN7zazoBy-bohH6eQ5fnb3VrTWAphHQXQoTC4XjZY7DUiECi8-aPSzDVrSwcWLbKgAxMAYEDnS43FW5HBPRNZ6BINgyNhWaRyBTYd4vb7LaAiZYQZLQNzQHDyd4kBzfXQcI5sBAARw4GD3xiXKBX2DXb2lD3JbymZDBXWfL9fr4Afu+0jbjpUU46mxbNsXQFf8WS9LoXn9T4-RoOgByHEcZHkNgcHeCNpxgOcoEXZdV18N5nl9aBEhQJJdk3aBt13A8jxPM8LyvN0CxZO8Hy6WhPy47jnF+IA)

Comment: Thx for this long answer. I should have precised that class `UserEntity` is intended to be consumed by `class-transformer` / `class-serializer` (working in Nestjs) and I was looking for some clean way to chain related entities.  Using Prisma I get types but to validate or transform response objects they have to be passed as a class instance. 
It looks like `class UserEntity<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseEntity<T> implements User` allows to chain them and get a reasonable typing... still investigating

Comment: If you need class only for validation, you may be interested in [Typia](https://github.com/samchon/typia); it also [supports Prisma](https://typia.io/docs/utilization/prisma/) and offers a [compatibility helper for NestJS](https://nestia.io/).